# iOS Simulator Console Stops Printing if App Restarted

Tags: ios, core-data, console

I've developed an app that uses CoreData - if I just run it, it works perfectly fine and logs everything appropriately in console so I can see what's going on.

All my database stuff works, no errors anywhere and all parts of my app seem to work appropriately.  It's pulling all the appropriate data and spitting it out in the console.

I wanted to see what happens if a user closes the app, then reopens the app - if it continues to work appropriately.  When I close the app in the simulator - then reopen it, the console is no longer logging anything.  All text getting printed to the console is no longer appearing.

Is this the intended design of the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to catch messages that come through just as the app is restarting, but once it has started you can attach to it again with `Attach to Process` in the XCode Debug menu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. If you want "lightweight" solution - look at connected device console log in Organizer.